# Is it possible to use grafana to write query results of SQL DBs (postgres / mysql) into influxDB ?

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I would like to query several different DB's using grafana, and in order to keep metrics history I would like to keep it in influxDB.

I know that I can write my own little process that holds queries and send it to influx, but I wonder if its possible by grafana only?

Comment: Your own little process, pls. I would suggest to collect all in the InfluxDB in raw form, and then query it from Grafana.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to use Grafana to do that. Grafana isn't really an appropriate tool for transforming/writing data. But either way, its query engine generally just works with one single datasource/database at a time, rather than multiple, which is what you'd need here.